# How to make two functions with same names in Base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, virtual-functions

This code compiled.

```
struct A
{
    const int *getX() const
        {
            return &x;
        }

    int *getX()
        {
            const A *thisConst = this;
            return const_cast<int *>(thisConst->getX());
        }


    void f()
        {
            int *p = getX();
        }

    int x;
};
```

But this code didn't.

```
struct I
{
    virtual const int *getX() const = 0;

    int *getX()
        {
            const I *thisConst = this;
            return const_cast<int *>(thisConst->getX());
        }
};

struct A : I
{
    virtual const int *getX() const
        {
            return &x;
        }

    void f()
        {
            int *p = getX();
        }

    int x;
};
```

'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'int *'

I know that if I will give different names it will be compiled. But are there ways without functions renaming?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to be asking the same thing as your question... could you change one of the two to avoid confusion? Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want to compile this code without getX renaming.

Answer (score 1):

> 'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'const A *' to 'int *'

I didn't get this error while trying to compile your program, instead I got

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

To compile successfully I corrected following line

```
int *p = getX();
```

to

```
const  int *p = getX();
```

`const int *` and `int*` are two different types, you can't assign it directly without cast or modify the type of the variable `p`.

Comment: I made some edits. I know difference between `const T *` and `T *`. But I need to be able to get `T *` because object which I replaced by `int` in this question calls not const method.

Comment: @Ufx if you edit do it  as additional explanation instead changing the posted question. I don't know what you have edited.

Comment: See an example for editing question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063331/i-i-is-undefined-is-i-fooi-also-undefined#31063331