# i = i++; is undefined. Is i = foo(i++) also undefined?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

For example:

```
int foo(int i) { return i; }

int main()
{
  int i = 0;

  i = i++;      // Undefined
  i = foo(i++); // ?

  return 0;
}
```

What would the current ISO C++ standard specify for this case?

**EDIT:**

Here's where I get confused:

> Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.
>
> If a side effect on a scalar
>   object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation
>   using the value of the same scalar object, and they are not potentially concurrent (1.10), the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value
>   computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression
>
> Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically
>   sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with
>   respect to the execution of the called function.

So it seems you could have a value computation on the left side of the assignment  (just `i`), and a side effect on the right side (the modification of `i` from `i++`) which aren't sequenced with respect to each other.

**EDIT2**:

For anyone who finds themselves here, there is a really great explanation about sequencing that I found [here](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/c++-sequenced-before-graphs.html).

Comment: `foo(i++)` is fine, `foo(i, i++)` is undefined

Comment: foo(i++) makes a copy hence not increasing its value if you try to print i after the function call. But foo(++i) actually does. Look at the assembly

Comment: `foo(i++)` is fine, `foo((i, i++))` is also fine.

Comment: This is fine going back to C90. The argument expressions of a function call are all evaluated, then a sequence point takes place before the function is called. The assignment cannot happen until the function returns, because it requires the return value.  Where things can go awry is when someone makes `foo` into a macro.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The last sentence in your quote says **"that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function"** so the question is whether the increment and the assignment are "otherwise specifically sequenced before or after" the function body.

1.9 [intro.execution] p15 has the answer:

> When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every value computation and side effect
>   associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is
>   sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function. [ *Note:* Value
>   computations and side effects associated with different argument expressions are unsequenced. — *end note* ]

So the increment of `i` happens before the function body, and the assignment to `i` happens after the function returns, so it is perfectly well-defined.

In pre-C++11 terminology, the function call introduces a sequence point between the increment and the assignment.

Comment: Can you check my edit? For assignment: "the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands". So you could have a value computation on the left side of the assignment, with just `i`. Then you can have `i++` evaluated before the `foo` function call. This would result in a value computation on `i` and a side effect from the increment that are unsequenced with respect to each other, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: From the standard: "value computations (including determining the identity of an object for glvalue evaluation and fetching
a value previously assigned to an object for prvalue evaluation)."

Comment: The key is that there is no side effect for the value computation of the left hand side, and the value of the LHS is not needed. It's an lvalue evaluation, so just determines the identity of the object. The side effect only happens after the function returns, and that has to be after evaluation of the function argument. "If **a side effect on a scalar object** is unsequenced relative to either __another side effect on the same scalar object__ or a value computation **using the value of the same scalar object**, and they are not potentially concurrent (1.10), **the behavior is undefined.**"

Comment: "The side effect only happens after the function returns" that's my issue. There's a  side effect of `i++` which occurs *before* `foo()` is run. So basically it's possible for there to be a "value computation" for `i` on the left hand side of the assignment, and a side effect from `i++` before the (in old terms) sequence point of the function call is reached. i.e. the function does not introduce a sequence point between the value computation on the left hand side of the assignment and the side effect of `i++`.

Comment: But it's not undefined for value computations to be unsequenced! Read the text you quoted again, and read what it says is undefined. There are two side effects, the increment, and the assignment, but one happens before the function call and one happens after. The value computation of the LHS _before_ the call has no side effect and doesn't use its value, so the fact is it unsequenced relative to the increment does not cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: From the standard: "If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object **OR** a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, and they are not potentially concurrent (1.10), the behavior is undefined." So what I'm saying is there's a value computation **and** a side effect which aren't sequenced with respect to each other.

Comment: "or a value computation **using the value**". The value computation of the LHS **DOES NOT USE ITS VALUE**. See p12, for glvalue evaluation it just determines the identity of the object, it doesn't use its value. But I've said that in every comment above already, and you are still ignoring the "a value computation **using the value**" part.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. This clears things up. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 11):

`i = foo(i++);` is fine, because `i++` is executed before `foo()` is called. A copy of `i` is made, `i` is then incremented, then the copy is passed to `foo()`.  It is the same as doing this explicitly:

```
int tmp = i++;
i = foo(tmp);
```